# max_questions - keeping score [mysql / php]

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a web application using php / MySql.

I am moving and transforming a large amount of data and trying to do so in a short space of time, so am running a number of parallel sessions.

My application is on a shared server, so I don't have access to change a whole heap of parameters (including max_questions).

I am running into exceeded max_questions errors on frustratingly frequent basis.

I've tried to streamline my code to minimise the problems (looking for ways to combine several queries into one), but that has only helped marginally.

Given that I do not have access to change the max_questions value; is there anyway that I can read how many questions out of my max I have used up, so that I can throttle the execution to remain below the limit?

So at the moment I am kicking off overnight jobs that fail after maybe a couple of hours, whereas if I slowed them down to run at say 80%, they might run for the whole 10 hours.

Is there anyway I can see if I am above say 95% of my allowance at any point in time and therefore slow down my processing when this is the case?

Grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Your best bet is to use a try/catch block and check the exception for that error string. If detected, initiate a sleep/cooldown period. Also, take a look at this: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31190/viewing-mysql-account-resource-limits

Comment: Jeremy - Thanks. That's a bit of a "DOH!" moment for me. 
OF COURSE if I just trap out the max_questions error, I can then have the procedure pause out the remainder of the hour (or less?) and restart. 
(I'm new on using this site, but I think you posted as a comment rather than an answer? So I don't think I can vote you up unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're bombarding MySQL too fast, it won't matter if you bundle up your queries -- even if bundling them up is a good idea to have your script finish sooner. You will simply hit the limit with more complex queries. You can use [`usleep`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php) to throttle execution, you'd then have to factor your throttle interval to a delay that ensures your script will not have time to execute hourly queries beyond the limit.

First find out the value of `max_questions`, or max. hourly queries for a single user. (Defined in db/table `mysql/user`.) Then register the start-time of your script, and keep count of how many queries you've executed. When you're close to the limit, set your script to sleep until 60 minutes is full, then reset the timer. If you use a combination of this approach and a constant microsleep throttle, you are less likely to hit other limits (e.g. `max_user_connections`) your host may have in place.

If your host allows you to have multiple MySQL users that can access a single database, you can set up a separate user for each parallel session, or set up a user rotator into your DB connect routine. (If not, you could split up the database, if it's possible to isolate different aspects of the process, and delegate different tasks to different users. At that point, I'd rather get me a basic VPS for $5/month.)

For general reference, linking to MySQL manual on [Account Resource Limits](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-resources.html). When creating or altering users, `MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR` is used, which translates into the `max_questions` column. If you have the required permissions, you can issue a `FLUSH USER_RESOURCES` statement to reset the counters for usage limits other than `max_user_connections` (will reset all hourly limits).

**Edit:** You can configure your database to keep user stats in a table under the `mysql` database. Set `userstat = 1` in your config, restart server, and statistics are available with `SHOW USER_STATISTICS`. This works at least with MariaDB ([info](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/using-resource-monitoring-avoid-user-service-overload)) and Percona ([info](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/diagnostics/user_stats.html)) forks of MySQL; however I can't seem to find information on this for MySQL itself, it may require the installation of a third-party plugin.

Comment: Yet to figure out where the current values of a user's resource limits are stored (doesn't seem to be in the `mysql` database where the limit is set), but a fair bet is you won't have access to that either, wherever it is. Easier to just keep track of your query count in any case.

Comment: Thanks - understand the point re bundling, but the mysql interactions are not the time limiting factor. I can run at least 6 parallel processes without degrading speed. 
I had looked at keeping track of how many queries issued, I seem to be hitting the limit at c. 30k transactions (should be 50) - there is some additional web traffic generating queries, but not that much! Hence wanting to see if I could "read" the current "score" and act on that.
If not possible I guess I'll need to resort to a bit of trial and error!
(I don't have access to multiple users on the db by the way).

Comment: The current status of where you're at with your limit is apparently stored in MySQL's logs -- and fetching the info would be less than a trivial op. Not something that you want to be doing all the time! If you have read permissions to the `mysql/user` table, you can run a query and find out the exact value of your limit. Otherwise e.g. just set the counter running and write it to a file after each query, and see where the count is when it's terminated. If you have queries from web traffic atop, obviously deduct that from your script's cap with some extra atop so your sites don't go defunct.

Comment: Thanks Marcus - that's the answer to the question I posed so I've given you the tick! Much appreciated.


In practise Jeremy's answer let me move forward on this.

What I've done is to capture the max_questions error then pause for 5 minutes before trying again. Which lets me kick off the processes, with confidence I won't wake up to find they failed 10 minutes after I went to bed.

The results are a bit puzzling - at times the processes seem to be able to run well beyond where max_questions should kick, at other times it seems to pause considerably earlier. But all is good now!

Comment: Cheers @JasonDers. Not sure what sorts of database ops you're doing, but re: Jeremy's suggestion, do you then implement a transaction rollback or equivalent when the error is hit? So you don't end up skipping the query that bounced. BTW I updated the answer yesterday with notes on configuring user stats etc., but you probably don't have necessary permissions for doing that either. If you need to be doing this sort of stuff on a regular basis, really I'd consider setting up a basic $5/month unmanaged VPS, instead of putting up with shared hosting...

Comment: Hey Markus - because I'm almost totally 'self taught' (with the help of sites like this) -  I don't fully understand what you mean by rollback in this context. I'm only doing one 'write' per loop, so I'm simply trapping out the error and retrying the write every 5 (could be any number) minutes - any other error than max_questions and the procedure terminates. Probably not the most elegant or correct solution, but it works.
I may consider going for a hosting uprgrade at some point, but for the moment the particular challenge I am facing is one off, which I think I've resolved.

Comment: Basically just ensuring that you're not skipping a query that failed. Transactions/rollbacks (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-syntax-transactions.html) would only be relevant if you ran a series of queries where failure mid-process could mean corrupted data. Glad to hear it's working out for you.